# DVD player not reading DVD RW

Tags: dvd

Okay so what I did is that I erased everything from my DVD RW and burned some movies on it. After doing that I tried to run DVD in my DVD/DiviX player and it said `DVD Error`. Now my question is, why? It worked before I erased it.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you tried to run it in your DVD/divx player do you mean your external one hooked up to a tv ?. If so have you ever played DVD-RW's on it before, as rewritable dvd's can be really funny in dvd players, most dvd players will play DVD-R's no problem, but quite a lot have problems playing DVD-RW's
.

Comment: There were 4 movies on that DVD, and I played it normally on my DVD Player which is connected to TV yes. After that I wanted to erase DVD and put new movies on it and I did that. Now it wont load it anymore. Im trying to find a way to fix that if possible.

Comment: Ah ok, I see, try erasing it again, it might not have erased the disk properly.

Comment: By the way, basic question, is the disk clean ?, as if you wrote it with any crap on the surface it would have corrupted the write, does the disk play on the computer ?.

Comment: disk works fine on pc